# Need to refresh to make refind recognize Windows

Tags: arch-linux, boot, refind

I just installed Arch on my system alongside Windows and I'm having problems to make `refind` recognize the `Windows` entry.

I have 2 hard disks which the first one is where Windows is installed and the second one is where I installed arch.

Firstly I tried using `grub2` but I didn't manage to make the windows entry work... After this I tried `refind` and the first boot Windows showed up and booted correctly. The second boot, the windows entry disappeared and I can only make it appear again when I press ESC to make `refind` refresh the entries... It's not a huge deal for me press ESC to show up windows, but I would like to leave windows as default since I use this computer mostly to play games and secondly to study/work (which I use linux for).

I tried to change this in the refind configuration but it didn't work also:

```
also_scan_dirs boot,/dev/nvme0n1p2:EFI/Microsoft/Boot
```

Any idea on how to fix this?